# I have an aws amplify app and I would like to let users create and edit S3 objects that other users can only read?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I've developed a web application using AWS Amplify, which enables users to store objects in an S3 bucket. Presently, users can create private objects that are exclusively accessible to them, and these are located at:
S3 bucket / private / cognito identity id / object

Additionally, they can create public files that any user can read or write, and these are found at:
S3 bucket / public / object

I'd like to enable users to create objects with read/write permissions for the owner and read-only access for all other users. I tried using the "protected" privacy level and the objects are stored as follows:
S3 bucket / protected / cognito identity id / object

When a user other than the object's owner attempts to read the object, an "access denied" error is thrown due to the differing cognito identity id.

I traced through the amplify storage library and it seems that identityId is added to the object path when using private or protected access levels.